# What is the error in my PLSQL program to find vowels in a string entered and to check if its palindrome?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the code which I wrote for a PLSQL program to count the number of vowels in a string which is entered by the user and also check whether its a palindrome or not and show that as outptut.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  STR VARCHAR(30);
  N VARCHAR(30);
  REV VARCHAR(30);
  L NUMBER(10);
  TEMP VARCHAR(30);
  C NUMBER(10):=0;
BEGIN
  STR:='&STR';
  TEMP:=STR;
  L:=LENGTH(STR);
  FOR I IN 1..L
  LOOP
    REV:=(REV||SUBSTR(STR,L,1));
    N:=SUBSTR(STR,I,1);
    IF N IN ('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u')
    THEN
      C:=C+1;
    END IF;
    L:=L-1;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTERED STRING IS '||STR);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NUMBER OF VOWELS IN THE STRING IS:'||C);
  IF(TEMP=REV)
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITS A PALINDROME');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITS NOT A PALINDROME');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

I tried this program in SQL*Plus and I am getting this as output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpmVl.jpg)

any fixes??!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution - rather than a fix of your code.

```
declare
  STR varchar2(30);
  REV varchar2(30);
  C number(10) := 0;
begin
  STR:='&STR';
  select reverse(STR) into REV from DUAL;
  C := regexp_count(STR, '[AEIOUaeiou]');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(C));
  if STR = REV then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Palindrome.');
  end if;
end;
```

Refer to [Oracle 'reverse' function](http://psoug.org/definition/reverse.htm) and [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014)

Here is sample output when I run the above code in *SQL*Plus*

```
Enter value for str: MADAM
old   6:   STR:='&STR';
new   6:   STR:='MADAM';
2
Palindrome.
```

### EDIT

My fixes for your code.

```
DECLARE
  STR VARCHAR2(30);
  N CHAR(1);
  REV VARCHAR2(30);
  L NUMBER(10);
  C NUMBER(10):=0;
BEGIN
  STR:='&STR';
  L:=LENGTH(STR);
  FOR I IN 1..L
  LOOP
    N:=SUBSTR(STR,(I * -1),1);
    REV:=REV||N;
    IF N IN ('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u') THEN
      C:=C+1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTERED STRING IS '||STR);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NUMBER OF VOWELS IN THE STRING IS:'||C);
  IF(STR=REV) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITS A PALINDROME');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITS NOT A PALINDROME');
  END IF;
END;
```

Refer to [SUBSTR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) function.

Comment: I'm not sure that recommending someone to use undocumented functions is a good idea. REVERSE being one of them. WM_CONCAT another (which doesn't even exist in 12c and above versions) so - anyone who used those might need to fix (a lot?) of their code once Oracle simply removes them from future releases.